# get Links corresponding to error codes 404

Tags: python, web-scraping, http-status-code-404

I have approximately 500 player Links.
Apart from two, all the links return the response code 200.
However, I need exact links / urls that have the code 404.

```
for p in range(len(playerLinks)):
    
       
    page = playerLinks[p]
    response = requests.get(page, headers={'User-Agent': 'Custom5'})
    print(response.status_code)
    injury = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(injury, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find(id="yw1")
```

thank you very much for your support.
An example for a player Links(how those links look like) is this (but there are at least 500 different)

```
https://www.transfermarkt.de/Timothy Fosu-Mensah/verletzungen/spieler/315131']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with simple `if` statement.

```py
for p in range(len(playerLinks)):
    
       
    page = playerLinks[p]
    response = requests.get(page, headers={'User-Agent': 'Custom5'})

    if response.status_code == 404:
        print(page)

    injury = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(injury, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find(id="yw1")
```